# A dice is rolled 5 times, find the probability of getting exactly two times even number and exactly two times number greater than 3.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A dice is rolled 5 times, find the probability of getting exactly two times even number and exactly two times number greater than 3. 
The result should be  ≈ 0.0707 = 7.07 %. but i can't get it

Comment: Hint;  I would split it into cases.  Type I:  no overlap (so the even numbers must both be $2$ and the large numbers must both be $5$).  Type II:  exactly one roll is both even and large.  Type III:  two rolls are both even and large.

Comment: I tried to find probability with this conditions in one roll then to use that probability in binomial distribution but i don't know even if it's good way and how to find probability with this conditions in one roll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of $5$ rolls as an ordered sequence of $5$ slots to put numbers 1-6 in.

**Case 1:** Exactly two slots are even and greater than 3.

- Choose 2 slots (out of 5) to be even and greater than 3: ${}_5C_{2}$
- Each of those 2 slots can be 4 or 6: $2\times 2$
- The remaining 3 slots all must be odd and not greater 3 (1 or 3): $2^3$

**Case 2:** Exactly 1 slot is even and greater than 3.

- Choose $1$ slot to be even and greater than 3: ${}_5C_1$
- That slot can be 4 or 6: $2$
- Choose 1 slot out of remaining 4 to be even and not greater than 3: ${}_4C_1$
- That slot must be 2: $1$
- Choose 1 slot of remaining 3 to be greater than 3 and odd: ${}_3C_1$
- That slot must be 5: $1$
- Each of the remaining 2 slots must be odd and not greater than 3, that is 1 or 3: $2\times 2$

**Case 3**: No slot is even and greater than 3

- Choose 2 slots to be even and not greater than 3: ${}_5C_2$
- Those 2 slots must be 2: $1$
- Choose 2 slots (out of the remaining 3) to be greater than 3 and odd: ${}_3C_2$
- Those 2 slots must be 5: $1\times 1$
- The 1 remaining slot must be odd and not greater than 3, that is 1 or 3: $2$

Multiply the numbers within each case together and sum up 3 cases, then divide by $6^5$ to get $215/1944$.

Comment: For your case 1: "the remaining slots have to be odd and less than or equal to $3$", you have both $1$ and $3$ as possible values hence there are $8$ ways to do it.

Comment: Fixed that and some other places.

Comment: Well, for what it is worth that's the same answer I got.

Comment: Can some of you two write exactly every step in this, not by explanation but real numbers and result for every case cause i still can't get any of this results, and this what you got is not very near to that answer i have

Comment: @TheGruela I get the exact same answer, and I agree with the reasoning. So maybe your target answer is wrong?

Comment: @TheGruela I ran an experiment with a python script, and the result was always around 10-11%. So maybe your expected answer was not right.

Comment: Yes @HennoBrandsma It's possible that it's wrong answer, its for exam and professor gave me this result and i was afraid to fail exam if not get the same so i was just trying to get the same in any way

Comment: Yes @Myath obviously it's wrong answer I have and your answer is correct