# A die is rolled 5 times, find the probability of getting exactly two times even number and exactly two times number greater than 3.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A dice is rolled 5 times, find the probability of getting exactly two times even number and exactly two times number greater than 3. The result should be ≈ 0.0707 = 7.07 %.

This question is a follow-up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505559/a-dice-is-rolled-5-times-find-the-probability-of-getting-exactly-two-times-even).

Earlier i got hints and answers to separate it in 3 cases:

Case 1: Exactly two slots are even and greater than 3.

```
Choose 2 slots (out of 5) to be even and greater than 3: 5C25C2
Each of those 2 slots can be 4 or 6: 2×2
The remaining 3 slots all must be odd and not greater 3 (1 or 3): 2323
```

Case 2: Exactly 1 slot is even and greater than 3.

```
Choose 1 slot to be even and greater than 3: 
That slot can be 4 or 6: 2
Choose 1 slot out of remaining 4 to be even and not greater than 3: 
That slot must be 2: 1
Choose 1 slot of remaining 3 to be greater than 3 and odd: 
That slot must be 5: 1
Each of the remaining 2 slots must be odd and not greater than 3, that is 1 or 3: 2×2
```

Case 3: No slot is even and greater than 3

```
Choose 2 slots to be even and not greater than 3: 
Those 2 slots must be 2: 1
Choose 2 slots (out of the remaining 3) to be greater than 3 and odd: 
Those 2 slots must be 5: 1×1
The 1 remaining slot must be odd and not greater than 3, that is 1 or 3: 2
```

Then i have to multiply the numbers with each case together and sum up 3 cases, then divide by 6^5 to get 215/1944

How to calculate every single case before i sum up to get this result?? I don't know where i make mistake in calculation

Comment: Are you asking  people to go through every line with you or are there specific lines with which you don't agree?  You haven't posted your calculation so we really can't spot where your error is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A dice is rolled 5 times, find the probability of getting exactly two times even number and exactly two times number greater than 3.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505559/a-dice-is-rolled-5-times-find-the-probability-of-getting-exactly-two-times-even)

Comment: @lulu Check the question. This is not a duplicate but a follow-up to that question.

Comment: Case 1 should just $\binom{5}{2} \times 2^5$. It is in the original answer, BTW

Comment: Followup should happen at the other question!

Comment: @Aniket this question adds nothing to the original. Still, I withdrew my close vote.  I've posted a solution which effectively coincides with the original.  Arithmetic error is always possible in this sort of thing.  If there is such an error in my solution, I'd like to see where it is.

Comment: Is there a problem with my solution?  If so, I'd like to see where it is.  Otherwise, I fear this question is just going in circles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three cases, according to the possible number of overlaps.

We say a number is large if it is $>3$, small otherwise.

Case I: No overlap. There are two small even numbers and two large odd ones.

the only large odd number is $5$, the only small even number is $2$.  Thus we just have to pick $2$ slots to be occupied by $2$ ($10$ ways to do it)

and then $2$ slots to be occupied by $5$ ($3$ ways to do it)

and then populate the fifth slot with either $1$ or $3$. ($2$ ways to do that).  Hence $$10^*3^*2=60$$

Case II.  Exactly one point of overlap.

Pick the overlap slot ($5$ ways to do that).

Populate it ($2$ ways to do that)

Pick the slot for the small even number ($4$ ways to do that)

Populate it ($1$ way to do that)

Pick the slot for the large odd number ($3$ ways to do that)

Populate it ($1$ way to do that)

Populate the remaining two slots ($4$ ways to do that)

Hence $$5^*2^*4^*1^*3^*1^*4=480$$

Case III  Two overlaps

Pick the overlap pair ($10$ ways to do that)
Populate it ($4$ ways to do that)
populate the remaining three slots ($8$ ways to do that)
Hence $$10^*4^*8=320$$

So (barring arithmetic error) the ways to get what you want  number $$60+480+320=860$$  As there are $6^5$ total combinations the probability is $$\frac {860}{6^5}=\frac {215}{1944}\sim .1106$$